# React Router how to update the route twice in one render cycle

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I think it is an obvious limitation in *React* & *React Router*, but I'm asking maybe someone will have another idea, or someone else that will come here and will understand it impossible.

---

I have two *custom hooks* to do some logic related to the navigation. In the code below I tried to remove all the irrelevant code, but you can see the original code [here](https://github.com/baruchiro/use-route-as-state/blob/1a668cbc0b179bb6a38ae1d7520cfbab9eb70310/src/index.ts).

**Custom Hook to control the page:**

```js
const usePageNavigate = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const navigate = useCallback((newPage) => history.push(newPage), [history])
  return navigate
}
```

**Custom Hook to constol the QueryString:**

```js
const useMoreInfo = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const history = useHistory()
  const setQuery = useCallback((value) => history.replace(pathname + `?myData=${value}`), [history, pathname])
  return setQuery
}
```

Now you can see the **QueryString hook* is used the `location` to concatenate the query string to the current path.

The problem is that running these two in the same render cycle (for example, in `useEffect` or in `act` in the test) causes that only the latest one will be the end result of the router.

```js
const NavigateTo = ({ page, user }) => {
  const toPage = usePageNavigate()
  const withDate = useMoreInfo()

  useEffect(() => {
    toPage(page)
    withDate(user)
  }, [])

  return <div></div>
}
```

What can I do (except creating another hook to do both changes as one)?

Should/Can I implement a kind of "events bus" to collect all the `history` changes and commit them at the end of the loop?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why would you run both of them at the same time from a `useEffect` ? Shouldn't those changes be triggered by some kind of user action?

Comment: I knew someone will ask something like that. Yes. they are from the same user action. but this action is trying to update both the `routeParams` and `QueryString`, and for updating those, I have a different custom hook for each one to do internal logic related to.
https://github.com/baruchiro/use-route-as-state/issues/78

Comment: This sounds like an anti-pattern and I think your code would benefit from a refactor to get rid of this requirement. There's nothing wrong in calling `setState` twice from a `useEffect`, which would could cause a double update (if they are not batched). But to replace the `page` twice, it feels right that you'd get the last one as the result.

Comment: Yes, I also think so